# Chrome: Console hovering on the variable doesn't work

Tags: google-chrome

So this morning my Chrome Stable version updated from version 78 to 79.0.3945.79, and with this new update the code hovering is broken in the dev console.

To explain more exactly, if you put a breakpoint on some code line, and it triggered, in the previous versions you could have hovered a variable (this.something) and a small tooltip with all the variable data would have appeared above it. Since the 79 version this doesn't work anymore and no tooltip appears when hovering over such an element, or when highlighting one or one line of code like "object.name1.value", where before this .value was shown.

Did anyone else encounter this problem? I also had this on 79 when it was in Beta but I thought it was a bug so hence I used stable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a bug. For now, you can install chrome canary - Version 81. Thx to https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/16855096?msgid=22548123

Comment: So it is a bug. I thought they eliminated this tooltip and they didn't inform us. Thank you for the response,